# Join with conditions

Tags: sql-server

*emphasized text*I have 2 tables. First table have 3 columns namely SupplierId ,SupplierDetailID and entityid and second table has 2 column namely SupplierId and SupplierDetailID. In first table there are more than one combination of SUPPLIERID and Supplierdetailid due more than one entity id..I want to form left join on supplier Id field in such a way that only when suppliersDetailID is blank in first table it should take max value of SupplierDetailID from second tables for that particular SupplierId. 
Formed query will give first_table.supplierID,if first_table SupplierDetailID is blank then max of second table SupplierDetailID for particular supplierId,first_table entityid.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Px5OU.jpg)

Comment: Great. What have you tried?

Comment: [Here](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) is a great place to start.

Comment: Thats almost as great as a lmgtfy reply lol

Comment: Just adding some text to the description does not help make this more clear for anybody else. We don't know your project and can't see your screen. And it is becoming a wall of text because there is no attempt at making that legible.

Answer (score 1):

This SQL Query will work for you.

```
SELECT s1.SupplierID,
       ISNULL(s1.SupplierDetailID, MAX(s2.SupplierDetailID)) AS SupplierDetailID
FROM s1
    LEFT JOIN s2
        ON s1.SupplierID = s2.SupplierID
GROUP BY 
         s1.SupplierID,s1.SupplierDetailID;
```

s1 is first supplier table.

s2 is second supplier table.